# Disable listview alphabetic index by default

Tags: android, listview, alphabetical

I have problems with the listview in specific devices. It display alphabetic index in right side of screen in Karbonn phone shown beneath.

[image]

This is my listview.....

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

Comment: are you using default ListView ?

Comment: Yes, It is default ListView.

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false)
```

Refer [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(boolean))

Comment: Problem is still not solved, it displays and once i click app is being crashed.

Answer (score 1):

add in your xml

```
 android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
```

Like

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:focusable="false"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:clickable="false"
android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:divider="@null" />
```

Comment: Problem is still not solved, it displays and once i click app is being crashed.